# Elasticsearch composite query and aggregation results different doc_count value

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to query on my data set with composite query.
Here is my

**Query 1:**

```sh
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/index1-202103/_search?size=0&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter":[
        {
          "range":{
            "date":{
              "gte":"20210330",
              "lte":"20210330"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term":{
            "userid":"16114"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists":{
            "field":"opens"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists":{
            "field":"tags"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs":{
    "my_buckets":{
      "composite":{
        "sources":[
          {
            "from_domain_wise":{
              "terms":{
                "field":"domain"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "msp_wise":{
              "terms":{
                "field":"msp"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "fromaddress_wise":{
              "terms":{
                "field":"fromaddress"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "tag_wise":{
              "terms":{
                "field":"tags"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "rate_over_time":{
              "date_histogram":{
                "field":"opens.time",
                "interval":"1h"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

**Query 2**

```sh
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/index1-202103/_search?size=0&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter":[
        {
          "range":{
            "date":{
              "gte":"20210330",
              "lte":"20210330"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term":{
            "userid":"16114"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists":{
            "field":"opens"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists":{
            "field":"tags"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs":{
    "my_buckets":{
      "composite":{
        "sources":[
          {
            "from_domain_wise":{
              "terms":{
                "field":"domain"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "msp_wise":{
              "terms":{
                "field":"msp"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "fromaddress_wise":{
              "terms":{
                "field":"fromaddress"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "tag_wise":{
              "terms":{
                "field":"tags"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs":{
        "rate_over_time":{
          "date_histogram":{
            "field":"opens.time",
            "interval":"1h"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Both the results gives output for date histogram with different counts. When I checked, my findings were that Query1 is counting opens.time (FORMAT: 2021-03-30 15:15:45) fields duplicate values also whereas Query2 is counting opens.time only once if hour is same in single doc.

For example: if doc contains opens: `[{ "time": "2021-03-30 15:20:25" }, { "time": "2021-03-30 15:45:30" }]` then Query1 return `doc_count` as 2 where as Query2 returns `doc_count` as 1.

Can anyone please explain why my query is behaving like this in spite of both the queries having the same goal. I want result which Query2 gives using Query1.

**PS:** Elasticsearch version is 7.10

Answer (score 1):

Both queries do "have the goal" but notice where you apply the `date_histogram`:

[image]

In the first query it's used as a [composite sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_sub_aggregations), in the second as a [composite value source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_value_sources).